# IntegrityError at /project/new/

Tags: python, django

I am trying make a project creating part for my django app. but I get this error:

```
IntegrityError at /project/new/

NOT NULL constraint failed: project_project.author_id
```

This is my view:

**view.py**

```
def project_new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            project = form.save()
            project.author = request.user
            project.published_date = timezone.now()
            project.save()
            return redirect('blog/project_detail.html', pk=project.pk)
    else:
        form = ProjectForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/project_new.html', {'form': form})
```

This is my model
**models.py**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = RichTextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

this is my forms file
**forms.py**

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, help_text='Required.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, help_text='Required.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')
    project_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, help_text='Required')
    project_description = forms.CharField(max_length=10000, required=True, help_text='Required.')
    project_notes = forms.CharField(max_length=1000, required=False, help_text='Optional.')

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'project_name',
                  'project_description', 'project_notes')
```

And this is mt html file. I am not sure but in this part I cannot be sure about "button" code. I may be wrong
**project_detail.html**

```
<form method="POST" style="text-align: center" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='hidden' value='m3KqcAqxJtXsJLS8ZRfhlXvTiXc1G0K0Whojb71JSe4jDsHYPwuOWKPIlFELyGoQ'/>

    <p>
        <label for="id_first_name">name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" required id="id_first_name" maxlength="30"/>

    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="id_last_name">last name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" required id="id_last_name" maxlength="30"/>

    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="id_email">Email:</label><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" required id="id_email" maxlength="254"/>

    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="id_project_name">Project name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="project_name" required id="id_project_name" maxlength="30"/>

    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="id_project_description">Project description:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="project_description" required id="id_project_description" maxlength="10000"/>

    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="id_project_notes">Proje notes:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="project_notes" id="id_project_notes" maxlength="1000"/>

    </p>

    <button style="color: #9C1A1C; font-weight: bold" type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>

</form>
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Looks to me that you need a `ModelForm` here, not a *generic* `Form`.

Answer (score 0):

Your form `ProjectForm` should be a subclass of `forms.ModelForm` instead of `forms.Form`

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, help_text='Required.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, help_text='Required.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')
    project_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, help_text='Required')
    project_description = forms.CharField(max_length=10000, required=True, help_text='Required.')
    project_notes = forms.CharField(max_length=1000, required=False, help_text='Optional.')

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'project_name',
                  'project_description', 'project_notes')
```

**Update**

To add `author` which is a non nullable `ForeignKey`, you should add author object before the changes are committed to a database.

```
def project_new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            project = form.save(commit=False)
            project.author = request.user
            project.published_date = timezone.now()
            project.save()
            return redirect('blog/project_detail.html', pk=project.pk)
```

Comment: Now, it is give another error.
IntegrityError at /project/new/

Comment: what is the exception message? Integrity errors occurs when the relational integrity of the database is affected, e.g. a foreign key check fails, duplicate key, etc.

Comment: IntegrityError at /project/new/
NOT NULL constraint failed: project_project.author_id

Comment: That is logical, the `author` is not part of your form, but required, since it can not be `None`/`NULL`.

Comment: Now, Thanks to all of you I solve the problem.
Thank you a lot